# Above the fold SVG Stack graphic in <object> tag, fetched with Data attribute, loading slow

Tags: html, svg

I am loading .svg files with stacked images, to optimize loading time and keep vector graphics crisp. I am using one file for my icons & one for my logos variations.

**Problem**

Some of the graphics that I want to render are in my header or above the fold and are loading slow or loading after other page elements. I would like to load it as fast as when I was using a PNGs.

If possible I would like to avoid adding the SVG code directly into HTML as the graphics are being used site wide.

**HTML** (Pages are PHP)

```
<object data="images/charactir-logos.svg#charactir-logo-creative" 
type="image/svg+xml" alt=""></object>
```

I tried using the following to speed up rendering; without noticeable difference:

```
<link rel="preload" href="images/charactir-logos.svg" 
as="image" type="image/svg+xml">
```

**SVG Files**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg id="icon" class="icon" version="1.1" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
viewBox="0 0 250 300" enable-background="new 0 0 250 300"   
xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
rect, line { shape-rendering: crispEdges; }
svg .icon { visibility: hidden }
svg .icon:target { visibility: visible }
</style>
... following is duplicated for each graphic entry
<svg viewBox="0 0 250 300">
<g id="charactir-logo-creative" class="icon">
... path data here
</g>
</svg>
... end of entry
</svg>
```

The individual items in the .svg stack are hidden and retrieved using:

```
svg .icon { visibility: hidden }
svg .icon:target { visibility: visible }
```

I had used display: none & display: inline before this, without a significant effect.

Comment: Have you compared the loading time of using an `<img />` tag with the `src` as the SVG instead of the `<object />` tag? Generally, if I am just using an SVG for display and no CSS or scripts from the page need to reference it then I just use the basic `<img />` tag.

Comment: @madebydavid I just tried this and there is some improvement in speed, the <img> boxes are also not rescaling on load like the <object> boxes, which is great. 
The reason for using <object> is for the sake of browser compatibility for reading an SVG stack correctly. Microsoft Edge doesn't display the SVG stack at all, just leaves it blank. I believe older IE  versions don't either.

Comment: That's true, the support is not perfect :(  There are some fallback options however - https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-picture/

Comment: @madebydavid Thank you very much. I wanted to implement this, but couldn't get a good tutorial. But this will help a lot.